# SQL Server - Force shared lock on partition

Tags: sql-server, locking, partitioning

I am using partition switching to rebuild indexes on a staging table without dropping them on the partitioned table as in [microsoft's article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191160%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

I have what boils down to

```
BEGIN TRAN
ALTER INDEX IX_Working ON dbo.WorkingTable DISABLE

INSERT INTO dbo.WorkingTable ( Id, PartitionColumn, Values...)
SELECT Id, PartitionColumn, Values...
FROM PartitionedTable WITH (HOLDLOCK)
WHERE PartitionColumn <= @rightboundary
AND PartitionColumn > @leftboundary

INSERT INTO WorkingTable ( Id, PartitionColumn, Values...)
SELECT Id, PartitionColumn, Values...
FROM Imports

ALTER INDEX IX_Working ON WorkingTable REBUILD -- SLOW BIT

ALTER TABLE PartitionedTable SWITCH PARTITION @partition TO SwapTable
ALTER TABLE WorkingTable SWITCH TO PartitionedTable PARTITION @partition

TRUNCATE TABLE SwapTable
COMMIT
```

Now during this operation I need to block any updates to the partition being reindexed but still allow them on other partitions. The PartionedTable has lock escalation set to auto. I am trying to do this with the HOLDLOCK but I'm still able to do INSERT INTO PartionedTable (Id, @somevalueInTheRange, Values...) from another connection during the slow bit.

How can I block this while still allowing selects?

Comment: Might it help to turn off row & page locking so it escalates to table lock (actually partition in your case)?  ALTER INDEX [myindexname] ON [dbo].[PartitionedTable] SET ( ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = OFF, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = OFF)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use TABLOCKX along with HOLDLOCK? currently the select will put an SHARED lock which is not released because of HOLDLOCK. But SHARED lock wont prevent inserts.